# Change pointer cursor when hovering over map elements

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, uwp-maps

My UWP application contains a map with several POI. I am trying to change the mouse cursor from an arrow to a hand when hovering over specific poi to indicate its clickable.

This would change the cursor as soon as it enters the map still, as a simple test, I added a PointerEntered event for the mapcontrol and within it I have the following to change the cursor:

```
 Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = new Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor(Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursorType.Hand, 0);
```

It appears though the cursor does change however immediately gets overridden back to the pointer cursor.

Edit: Just realised When a poi is clicked (i.e. is selected) the cursor changes to a hand even when not over the map control until the poi is unselected. No good as I would like the cursor to change dynamically when hovering over a poi and revert back to cursor when moved away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Change pointer cursor when hovering over map elements

I'm afraid you can't edit the default cursor for map element, Because it has handled internally, it will not fired, even you has listen `PointerEntered` event, it consumed by the control and not passed up the control chain. If you do want this feature, the better way is post this feature with windows feed backhub app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works just like WinForms, I had to do something like this to click on labels (couldn't use link-labels), what I used was in the Mouse_Move event of the label and it was basically

```
if (Cursor.Current == Cursors.Default)
{
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.Hand;
}
```

and similar changes and behaviors due to the various conditions. This however got me a small issue: this statement changes the mouse graphic anytime you move on the control, but personally on Windows settings I use the trail graphic function for the mouse (leaving a trail of pointers whenever I move the mouse on the screen), what I suggested you disables this function, or better, it conceals it, since it "recreates" the mouse graphic for every move you do onto the control, and thus it "undoes" the graphic for the mouse and recreates it as a Hand (in my instance). If it doesn't concern you though, it works just fine.
Just I repeat myself: I use this on WinForms, but since it's C# I suppose it just will work(?)

Comment: Added a check like you have in your example but no difference to the behaviour I was already seeing with my example above unfortunately.